# scrollTop - the second click not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have two simple divs that onclick, run a scrollTop to move to a certain part of a website.

The problem is the following:

1. I click on the "make an offer" div. This brings me to the correct spot.
2. If I then click on the "instalments" div it scrolls to the top of the page.

Needed: to scroll to the correct point at all times.

The divs:

```
 <div id="button" class="Alan_button_blue">Make an Offer</div>

 <div id="instalments" class="Alan_button_2">Instalments</div>
```

The two scripts for the two divs are:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#button").click(function(){
           var offset = 1; //Offset of 1px
           $('body, html').animate({
               scrollTop: $("#section5").offset().top + offset
           }, 1500);
       });
   });      

   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#instalments").click(function(){
           var offset = 1; //Offset of 1px
           $('body, html').animate({
               scrollTop: $("#section6").offset().top + offset
           }, 1500);
        });
    });     
</script>
```

If anyone could help, that would be great!

Comment: Where is your `#section6` div located on page? Is it near the top?

Comment: Hi Mohit -- so #section6 is below #section on the html.  I was thinking iof changing the divs to buttons...maybe that would do it...

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code and it works perfectly. I can't say whats the issue...

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#button").click(function(){
                var offset = 1; //Offset of 1px
                $('body, html').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#section5").offset().top + offset
                }, 1500);
            });
        });      

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#instalments").click(function(){
                var offset = 1; //Offset of 1px
                $('body, html').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#section6").offset().top + offset
                }, 1500);
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <div id="button" class="Alan_button_blue" style="padding:50px;background:lightgray;margin-bottom:50vh;">Make an Offer</div>

        <div id="section5" style="width:100%;height:50vh;background:#aaafff"></div>
        
        <div id="instalments" class="Alan_button_2" style="padding:50px;background:darkblue;color:white;margin-bottom:50vh;">Instalments</div>
        
        <div id="section6" style="width:100%;height:50vh;background:#333333"></div>
        
        <div style="height:75vh;"></div>
```